# What is the best way to integrate Dependency Injection using Unity when static methods are used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

Im faced with an impending upgrade to an ASP.NET site and I am thinking of introducing DI using Unity.  I have researched the ASP.NET DI side of things and have 2 options (Global.asax or IHttpModule).  Im happy to use either.

As always, there is a legacy object model in place that I would like to upgrade/change.  I would like to go down the route of Constructor injection (passing in the DAO) however, each object has a mix of static and instance methods that both currently call into the DB using SqlCommand objects themselves.  I want this removed to provide DB independence, therefore can anyone suggest the best way to do the DI in this case?  Im open to drastic changes if they are needed.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
       public ExampleClass(int test)
       {
           TestProperty = test;
       }

       public int TestProperty {get; set;}

       public int Save()
       {
          // Call DB and Save
          return 1;
       }

       public static ExampleClass Load(int id)
       {
          // Call DB and Get object from DB
          return new ExampleClass(1);
       }

}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove all static methods and introduce some abstractions you should be good to go:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public int TestProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    ExampleClass Load(int id);
    int Save();
}

public class RepositorySql: IRepository
{
    // implement the two methods using sql
}
```

and in your ASP page:

```
private IRepository _repo = FetchRepoFromContainer();
public void Page_Load() 
{
    var someObj = _repo.Load(1);
    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: My intention was to use Enterprise Library 4.1 for data access.  The DAO im thinking of will largely be used to break up the Data access into functional areas.  Also i didnt think Static methods could be defined in an interface?  Im really looking for a way to use DI with static methods or for suggestions on a better way of doing things

Comment: Static methods cannot be defined in an interface.

Comment: i was thinking that removing the statics would be the way to go.  I was just hoping to avoid it as it'll be a lot of work in limited time, as the whole site is being re-written too

Comment: You do not need static methods. The repository example is a great way to go. You have instance methods in the repository implementation that correspond to the old static methods you want to get rid of. In a project of mine, I use a different approach - I use DTOs for my business objects, and for each object I have a service that fetches, lists, filters, saves and deletes a certain DTO (for instance User DTO will have a UserService and so). The service is referenced by interface and the implementation is free to use persistence logic of its own.